# Emulating __uint128_t

Tags: c++, c++11, bitwise, integer, overloading

I developed a lot of code locally with `__uint128_t` only to find out that it is not available on the target platform.

I am now trying to write my own struct that emulates the operators of `__uint128_t` I need: `=`, `~`, `^`, `&`, `|`, `^=`, `&=`, `|=`

This is the code I have now, which will be compiled with a C++11 compiler:

```
struct board_t {
    uint64_t hi;
    uint64_t low;    

    board_t operator~() const {
        return {~hi, ~low};
    }

    board_t operator|(const board_t & rhs) const {
        return {hi | rhs.hi, low | rhs.low};
    }

    board_t& operator|=(const board_t & rhs) {
        hi |= rhs.hi;
        low |= rhs.low;

        return *this;
    }

    // Complete equivalent functions for &, ^, &= ^=
};
```

- Will anything behave unexpectedly with this code?
- Do I need to create a constructor? Is the usage of the `{}` `struct` initializer good form?
- Do I need to override the assignment operator?
- Are there other ways to improve this code, style, correctness and speed?

Answer (score 4):

### Will anything behave unexpectedly with this code?

For that to answer we would need the expectations. Most users will expect a number type to behave like the `int`s do.

What does that mean in your example?

- your type should be usable in an `if(number)` (this also includes `if(!number)`)
- your type should be comparable with other `int` types, nobody wants to write `number == board_t{0, 3}` instead of `number == 3`  (this probably means you should write an implicit conversion from `int` to `board_t`

Surely there are other things you need to mimic from the `int`s.

### Do I need to create a constructor? Is the usage of the {} struct initializer good form?

Given the fact that you should provide something like `board_t(int)` you will need to provide the other constructors as well.

Internal functions (that know about the internal format of `board_t` might use the "struct initialize" but in general I would avoid it as it introduces dependencies on the inner layout.

### Do I need to override the assignment operator?

No, the default generated one will simply call the assignments on the members as well which is fine.

### Are there other ways to improve this code, style, correctness and speed?

Yes:

- why is the type called `board_t`?
- if the user should be able to supply values you could generate an [own literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) for this purpose
- define binary operators like `operator+` outside the class to get "more symmetric" code (this makes both operands eligible for automatic conversions instead of only the right hand side)
- the previous point may also be applied for unary operators that don't change the internal representation of the object (like `operator~()`)

All in all your design should be:

If the platform supports `uint128` the type should only be an alias of it and if it does not support this type, then your class should behave as much as `uint128` as possible (so on platforms that support it your code should do the same for both "implementations").

Comment: Thanks! I will not use this struct as a number, but to represent a gameboard. Hence no need for the +-/* operators or the need for conversion to smaller/bigger types,  and the name `board_t`. The if(variable) case is indeed something I forgot. I can't find how to do that, any pointers?

Comment: How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6242768/760746) for the `bool` conversion?

Comment: If you really want to represent a board (whatever that means in your context) I would advice you to use [`std::bitset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) instead.

Comment: @LokiAstari: The wording was wrong (and I changed the paragraph now). What I meant was: For types that behave like `int`s the default copying, which is shallow (and behaves like bitwise copy on builtin types), is usually sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

> Will anything behave unexpectedly with this code?

The default behavior of constructor/destructor and assignment operator (when no pointers are involved) is what you would expect. So yes it looks like it will behave just fine.

> Do I need to create a constructor?

No. The way way you are using struct assignment is fine. **BUT** personally I would provide one so that you can construct this object from a single short/int/long. That way you can construct from a single integer literal.

> Is the usage of the {} struct initializer good form?

It works as you expect. So it looks fine to me.

> Do I need to override the assignment operator?

No. The compiler generated one will do what you expect.

> Are there other ways to improve this code, style, correctness and speed?

The only change I would make, is to define the operator X in terms of the assignment operator X.

```
// The assignment version of operator '|'
board_t& operator|=(const board_t & rhs) {
    hi  |= rhs.hi;
    low |= rhs.low;

    return *this;
}

// The normal version of operator '|'
board_t operator|(const board_t & rhs) const {
    return board_t(*this) |= rhs;
}
```